# SignalR Configuration On Proxy DNS Server For NGINX

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, nginx, websocket, signalr

Good Morning

I am Facing Issue in SignalR Configuration , Let me Explain

My Functionality Work Perfectly In Dev & UAT Environments But it's Not Working On Production, Client Use Private/ Public DNS For Showing Application & We are using NGINX For Hosting.

Firstly I thought I make Multiple Hub URL & It's Resolve My Issue But Not.

Please Kindly Suggest Any Process Or Configuration For Resolving This.

Thanks
Kuldeep Singh

I Got this Solution
https://docs.wallarm.com/admin-en/configure-dynamic-dns-resolution-nginx/

But this one Is Paid

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Your question seems more of a configuration issue.  Not sure where it belongs though..  perhaps Serverfault?

Comment: Hello Kuldeep, I saw you have post a same issue in QA platform, and could you check the details I shared and try it, waiting for your update.